# Numbering equations in aligned environment

Tags: align, numbering, alignat, equation-number

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
\xi(z)=0
&\iff  
\begin{pmatrix}
\pi_P \circ z \circ \iota_P & \pi_P \circ z \circ \iota_Q \\
\pi_Q \circ z \circ \iota_P & \pi_Q \circ z \circ \iota_Q
\end{pmatrix}
= 0 \\
&\iff 
\begin{aligned}
\pi_P \circ z \circ \iota_P = 0 ,\\
\pi_P \circ z \circ \iota_Q = 0 ,\\
\pi_Q \circ z \circ \iota_P = 0, \\
\pi_Q \circ z \circ \iota_Q = 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

which produces the following snippet

[image]

My question is: How can I number\label the four subsequent equations in my own (numbering or labeling by letters\names or otherwise)?.

I need any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the unstarred `align`-environment as the outer shell and omit the inner `aligned` environment. Then you can suppress the automatically generated numbers in the lines that you don't need with `\nonumber`.

Comment: I need the four equations to be grouped (or gathered) together as shown in the snippet. @Lupino

Comment: Are the final four lines necessary or even useful? Stating that a matrix is zero is the same as stating that all its entries are zero. Be more trustful in your readers.

Comment: It's necessary. I need the four equations to be grouped together as seen but just with equation numbering.

Comment: The `\tag{}` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somethinglike this?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    ξ(z)=0 \notag
    &\iff
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \pi_P ∘ z ∘ \iota_P & \pi_P ∘ z ∘ \iota_Q \\
    \pi_Q ∘ z ∘ \iota_P & \pi_Q ∘ z ∘ \iota_Q
    \end{pmatrix}
    = 0 \\[1ex]
    &\iff
    \begin{aligned}
    \pi_P ∘ z ∘ \iota_P & = 0 , &\qquad & (a)\\
    \pi_P ∘ z ∘ \iota_Q & = 0 , & & (b)\\
    \pi_Q ∘ z ∘ \iota_P & = 0, & & (c)\\
    \pi_Q ∘ z ∘ \iota_Q & = 0. & & (d)
    \end{aligned}%
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's too close. But I need to the labeling `(a), (b), (c), (d)` to be the at the far right of the page as labeling equations in the `\align` environment seems.

Comment: And if you replace `\qquad` with `\hspace{6em}`?

Comment: Ok, it's fine. Thanks @Bernard .

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cross-reference the subequations, you need to use a single align environment, "move" the second `\iff` down to the middle of the subequation block and manually "indent" the next lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\nonumber
  ξ(z)=0
  &\iff
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \pi_P ∘ z ∘ \iota_P & \pi_P ∘ z ∘ \iota_Q \\
      \pi_Q ∘ z ∘ \iota_P & \pi_Q ∘ z ∘ \iota_Q
    \end{pmatrix}
                             = 0 \\[1ex]
  &\smash{\lower1.5\baselineskip\hbox{$\strut\iff\strut$}} \pi_P ∘ z ∘ \iota_P  = 0\,,\tag{1a}\\
  &\hphantom{\strut\iff\strut} \pi_P ∘ z ∘ \iota_Q  = 0\,,\tag{1b}\\
  &\hphantom{\strut\iff\strut} \pi_Q ∘ z ∘ \iota_P  = 0\,, \tag{1c}\\
  &\hphantom{\strut\iff\strut} \pi_Q ∘ z ∘ \iota_Q  = 0\,.\tag{1d}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I had to use `lualatex` and the `unicode-math` package with texlive2022 to get this to run, but the result should look something like that:

[image: rendering of aboves code]